# Talend Open Studio encoding issue

Tags: linux, eclipse, encoding, talend

I just unzipped Talend Open Studio v8.0.1 on a my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.

When I launch it I get the "license agreement" page and there is an encoding problem as shown in fig 1: [Talend 8 encoding problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6rXQ.png)

Using the app, I get the same issue in all multi-line fields, as show in fig 2 [tSOAP widget encoding problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/485OP.png). I imported some project and ran it: the console log shows the same encoding problem.

I tried various JDK (openjdk-11, Zulu openjdk-11, Oracle JDK 11, openjdk-13) and other versions of TOS (v6.4.1, v7.5.1). Tried various LANG environment variable values (fr_FR.UTF-8, en_IN.UTF-8). Tried to change fonts in Preferences. Tried to launch TOS from another newly created unix account. None of these attempts worked.

The nice Talend community support has no more ideas ([Talend community discussion](https://community.talend.com/s/feed/0D55b00006oBMSGCA4?language=en_US)).

The problem seems very difficult to reproduce (one colleage with same laptop and OS doesn't see it) so I ask here. I put an Eclipse tag as Talend Open Studio is an Eclipse Based App.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue than you:

[image: Bug display on console output]

And to solve this, I had to change some default config about font:

Menu **Window > Preferences**.

Then, on the left, go to **Talend > Appearance**, and change font used for "memo text font" and for "Console Text Font".

At the display, the font selector is showing the bug you described:

[image: Bug display on font selector]

...and, by selecting other font, this bug disappears.

[image: Bug display on font selector fixed by choosing other font]

For me it is working:

[image: Bug fixed in console output]

Seems simple but I have spent a lot of time to fixed that.

My config :

- Ubuntu 20.04
- OpenJDK 11.0.15
- Talend Open Studio 7.3.1 and 8.0.1

Comment: Hi Malenki, You got it ! I tried to change the font elsewhere, I didn't try here. It works now. Thank you !